# Why I cant reuse the mysqli->realquery several times without conecting again?

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to use mysqli for the first time, and I need to do some querys along my script. This is the basic flow:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "kiosk");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; }

$mysqli->real_query("SELECT * FROM screens WHERE name = '" . $screen_code . "'");
$res = $mysqli->use_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

print_r(_content($row['wcode']));
die();

function _content($wcode) {
  global $mysqli;
  $mysqli->real_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE wcode= '" . $wcode. "' ORDER BY id ASC");
  $res = $mysqli->use_result();
}
```

The mysql query is correct, already tested directly on mysql, if in _content i reconect to the database everything works, but i dont want to connect every time i want to query.

Comment: he is calling real_query twice, so the title makes sense and the code is relevant. I am curious what the error message is when he runs the codes as it is right now.

Comment: No error @Scott just blank output

Comment: Do you have error handling for the mysqli functions in your "real" code? E.g. do you check the return values of mysql::real_query() and maybe even print the error code/message in case of an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `use_result()` you have to take special care to retrieve the complete result set before issuing a new command/statement using the same connection. `store_result()` handles this procedure for you.
see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-use-result.html:

> When using mysql_use_result(), you must execute mysql_fetch_row() until a NULL value is returned, otherwise, the unfetched rows are returned as part of the result set for your next query. The C API gives the error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` if you forget to do this!

The same is true for the php/mysql API(s).

You can combine your two queries into one via [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)

```
SELECT
    c.foo, c.bar, c.baz
FROM
    screens as s
LEFT JOIN
    content as c
ON
    s.wcode=c.wcode
WHERE
    s.name = 'something'
ORDER BY
    c.id
```

and thereby avoid all this trouble...

Comment: Thank you! this was the problem, is incredible I got negative votes on my question just because people don't understood this is an actual migration problem from mysql to mysqli. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to MySQLi, just started using it yesterday.
Try to use `query()` instead of `real_query()` it works fine with me.

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I guess you need to put the function before `print_r()` because  it need to be defined before calling it